# Get username from session

Tags: php

I'm trying to get the member username from the session and can't find a real way

This is the code I reached:

```
<?php
session_start();
if( $session_name['member_username']="admin")
{//do something
} else { do smth}
```

Thank you

Comment: is `$session_name['member_username']` have data..

Comment: For one thing - you might want to look up the difference between the `=` and `==` operators in PHP

Answer (score 2):

Use double equal to (`==`) for comparison inside if

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if( $_SESSION['member_username']=="admin")
    {//do something
    } else { do smth}
?>
```

Comment: I have tried it but isnt working

Comment: i have updated my code plz check. Try `echo $_SESSION['member_username']` before if statement

Comment: It seems no data for member_username